# What is normal C getchar/putchar behaviour?

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

I am working through the exercises in Stephen Prata's "C Primer Plus", and have a question re. listing 8.1:

```
/* echo.c -- echoes input */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  char ch;

  while ((ch = getchar()) != '#')
    putchar(ch);
  // while ((ch = getchar()) != '.')
  //   putchar(ch);
  return 0;
}
```

The original code did not include the comments; I added them and they are the subject of my question.  If I uncomment those lines there is no discernible effect on the output.  It still ends at the `#` sign, without printing it.  No additional text is displayed and I am returned to the command prompt.

Why is that? Also, does the `#` get consumed by `getchar()`? That was why I included the second loop - I was trying to display any remaining characters in the buffer, out of curiosity. Obviously, I don't know what I'm doing!

Comment: Please note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) return an `int`. This is rather crucial if you ever want to check for `EOF`.

Comment: The `#` is consumed. To end the first loop, `getchar` must read the `#`, which is then assigned to `ch` and compared with the character constant `'#'`.

Comment: Thank you, both.  Prata does not introduce the concept of EOF until later, hence using the '#' character to terminate output at this point in the book.  When he does, he does declare ch as an int, with explanation.  However why does the second loop here give no output?

Comment: Because it's commented out, and you forgot to recompile when you uncommented it. Seriously though, there's no way for us to know that. Either you ended your input with `#.` or you fat fingered something.

Comment: @user3386109  I was careful to recompile once uncommented, but have rechecked.  When uncommented there is no effect on the output.  The '#' character is in the middle to the last sentence entered.  Do you get different behaviour?

Comment: I typed `hello# world. ignore this` and pressed the return key. The output was `hello world`

Comment: When in the first loop you encounter "#" then `ch = '#'`, after which you enter second loop and change the value of ch by calling getchar() function. Its working fine, attach your output in question

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I have two similarly named directories, with similar files, and was compiling in the wrong one.  My apologies, especially to @user3386109 who hit the nail more or less on the head.